# React Context Not Defined

Tags: reactjs

I have not been able to correctly use Context in my React app. Most of the docs are using class based components and I am attempting to do this with functional components.

The error states that `AppContext` is not defined.

`App.js` and `Header.js` are in different files.

If I add `console.log(React.useContext(AppContext))` immediately after `<AppContext.Provider value='AppName'>` The correct answer is logged. However, `AppContext` is not defined in `Header` here:

```
const app = useContext(AppContext);
```

Here is the current state of the code:

`App.js`

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';

const app = 'AppName';
const AppContext = createContext(app);

export default function App() {

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={ app }>
          {console.log(React.useContext(AppContext))} // returns 'AppName'
          <Header />
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

`Header.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

export default function Header() {
    const app = useContext(AppContext);
    console.log(app) // undefined because AppContext not defined
    return (
        <header>
            { app }
        </header>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move `React.createContext` outside of the component's body, pass a value for the context at the provider and use [`React.useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) for accessing the context's value.

```
const AppContext = React.createContext('CodeInABottle');

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AppContext.Provider value="someValue">
        <Router>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Header() {
  const someValueFromTheContext = React.useContext(AppContext);

  console.log(someValueFromTheContext); // 'someValue'
  return (
    <header>
      <Link to="/">{app}</Link>
    </header>
  );
}
```

here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xaysmc)

Comment: Even with these changes I still seem to be having issues. `Header` is in a different file than `App`. But that shouldn't matter no?

Comment: Moving `Bla` (in StackBlitz) to another file broke this solution

Comment: @Newb4YouBB Moving the variables to different files will obviously require import and export syntax, that's not something related to React context.